# Real and complex canonical forms of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms

How do I find the canonical form of

$$q_1(x,y,z)= 4x^2 +4xz+2yz$$

Now I have put it in matrix form as:

$$\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        4 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix} \right)
$$

So my question now is what do I do next? I know that the complex form canonical form has mixture of $1$ and $-1$ and the complex form only has 1 in it's diagonal. Do I just row reduce to get that form? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by canonical form? Please quote the exact definition, and say what book. Note: I publish articles about quadratic forms, and I am unaware of any such canonical form.

Answer (score 3):

$$q_1=4x^2+4xz+2yz=\left(\begin{matrix}x&y&z\end{matrix}\right)
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        4 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right)
$$

By Gauss method we have $$4x^2+4xz+2yz=(2x+z)^2-z^2+2yz=(2x+z)^2-(z-y)^2+y^2=\varphi_1^2(x,y,z)+\varphi_2^2(x,y,z)-\varphi_3^2(x,y,z)$$
so the signature is $(1,1,-1)$ and we know that the linear forms $\varphi_i$'s are linearly independant and if we denote by $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ the dual basis of the basis $(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3)$ then the matrix of $q_1$ in $\mathcal{B}$ is
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the canonical form is it?

Comment: Sami, I think this is probably about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia First, a real symmetric matrix can be orthogonally diagonalized over the reals. For each diagonal element, we can then take $\sqrt { |\lambda_j| },$ Meaning we can diagonalize (but not quite orthogonally anymore) to a matrix with all $1,0,-1$ diagonal entries. Finally, if we allowed complex numbers, we could have chosen $\pm \sqrt \lambda_j$ so as to get only $1,0$ on the diagonal. The person asking does not know enough, or work hard enough, to describe this correctly.

Comment: @WillJagy You're right, I'll try edit.

Comment: @WillJagy I edited my answer

Comment: Sami, works for me.